# PHP append Arrays inside Array with For Each Loop

Tags: php

I have the below code where I need to be able to append Arrays dynamically depending on how many images there are (up to 35). I have an array of objects with the number of images, is it possible to loop through them with a foreach loop and create an array for each one.

```
                array(
                    'name' => 'images',
                    array(
                        'name' => 'img',
                        'value'=> '',
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'id' => 'm',
                            'modTime' => $date,
                            'url' => '/FacadeImages/'.$Facade->Image,
                            'format' => 'jpg',
                        ),
                    ),
//                    Need to dynamically include the additional images here
                )
```

Want to do something like this:

```
            array(
                'name' => 'images',
                array(
                    'name' => 'img',
                    'value'=> '',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'id' => 'm',
                        'modTime' => $date,
                        'url' => '/FacadeImages/'.$Facade->Image,
                        'format' => 'jpg',
                    ),
                ),
           foreach($AdditionalImages as $AdditionalImage){
                array(
                    'name' => 'img',
                    'value'=> '',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'id' => '1',
                        'modTime' => $date,
                        'url' => '/AdditionalImages/'.$AdditionalImage->Image,
                        'format' => 'jpg',
                    ),
                ),
           }

            ),
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong then you need something like below to append the additional images on your main array,

```
$expected_array = [];
foreach($main_array as $key=>$array){
  $expected_array[] = $array;
  foreach($array['AdditionalImages'] as $AdditionalImage){
   $expected_array[$key][] = $AdditionalImage;
  }
}

print_r($expected_array);
```